# How to compare object

Tags: c#, .net

I really need to compare two objects with the same `class`, I have one grid with one list and need to check which one is the user changes. Here is the example

```
public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
}
```

I tried to use

```
Person p1 = new Person { Name = "Jay", Age = 25 };
Person p2 = p1;
Person p3 = new Person { Name = "Jay", Age = 25 };

Console.WriteLine(p1.Equals(p2));  // True
Console.WriteLine(p1 == p2);       // True

Console.WriteLine(p1.Equals(p3));  // False
Console.WriteLine(p1 == p3);       // False
```

In resume, I don't know to compare properly two objects, use `==` or `.equals`, please note that object two are copy of object one at the begin of process.

Comment: Look at overriding Equals and GetHashCode

Comment: `p1` and `p3` have only the same values of properties... but they are different objects. As @Matthew said - try to override `Equals` and `GetHashCode` methods (there you can implement how you would like to compare objects in order to say "objects are equal")

Comment: Your user example may be a simplification, but in general one should be very careful with defining equality for class types. There are people with my name and age that aren’t *me*. I usually advise against overriding Equals/GetHashCode and instead implement specific comparers like `class SameNameAndAgeComparer : IEqualityComparer<Person>` and compare using that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference between **==** operator and **Equals** resides in the fact that **==** operator is used to compare the references contrary to **Equals** which is used to compare contents .

Best regards .